# SSMS :: import XML file from OSM and parse nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, ssms, openrowset

I'm trying to import an `.osm` file (which is basically an `XML` file) into SQL Server.

If you want you can try the code by downloading a copy of the file I'm importing form [here](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/46.5071/6.6203) (just click "Export"). The XML file that I'm trying to parse looks like this:

```
 <node id="335558025" visible="true" version="9" changeset="56753970" timestamp="2018-02-28T12:01:28Z" user="SimonPoole" uid="92387" lat="46.5116200" lon="6.6254900">
  <tag k="addr:city" v="Lausanne"/>
  <tag k="addr:country" v="CH"/>
  <tag k="addr:postcode" v="1007"/>
  <tag k="amenity" v="car_sharing"/>
  <tag k="capacity" v="1"/>
  <tag k="mobility:station_id" v="3053"/>
  <tag k="name" v="Lausanne Harpe / Av. F. C. de la Harpe"/>
  <tag k="opening_hours" v="24/7"/>
  <tag k="operator" v="Mobility Genossenschaft"/>
  <tag k="source" v="http://www.mobility.ch/"/>
  <tag k="website" v="http://www.mobility.ch/"/>
```

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @TableName as NVARCHAR(35) = 'OSM_'         -- declare table name

DECLARE @x xml;
SET @x = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK 'C:\Users\franc\Desktop\Lausanne.osm',         -- Import file here
SINGLE_BLOB) AS x);
Select @x

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo. #TempTable                -- drop temp table if exist
EXEC('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.' + @TableName)      -- drop table if exist

CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
    [id]    NUMERIC NULL,
    [visible]   CHAR(5) NULL,
    [version]   NUMERIC NULL,
    [changeset] NUMERIC NULL,
    [timestamp] NVARCHAR(25) NULL,
    [user]  NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [uid]   NUMERIC NULL,
    [lat]   FLOAT NULL,
    [lon]   FLOAT NULL,
    [amenity]   NVARCHAR(50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable                              -- Insert data into table                           

SELECT 
id = OSMnode.value('@id', 'NUMERIC'),
visible = OSMnode.value('@visible', 'CHAR(5)'),
[version] = OSMnode.value('@version', 'NUMERIC'),
changeset = OSMnode.value('@changeset', 'NUMERIC'),
[timestamp] = OSMnode.value('@timestamp', 'NVARCHAR(25)'),
[user] = OSMnode.value('@user', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
[uid] = OSMnode.value('@uid', 'NUMERIC'),
latitude = OSMnode.value('@lat', 'FLOAT'),
longitude = OSMnode.value('@lon', 'FLOAT'),
amenity = OSMnode.value('(tag[@amenity="k"])[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
FROM
@x.nodes('/osm/node') AS OSM(OSMnode);

DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @TableName + ' FROM  #TempTable'
EXEC (@sql)

EXEC('SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo. #TempTable
```

Is working quite well but I cannot import the column "Amenity" which keep resulting in `NULL`:

[image]

So the whole problem is in this line:

```
amenity = OSMnode.value('(tag[@amenity="k"])[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
```

How can I parse that value?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tag[@k="amenity"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath expression, `tag[@amenity="k"]`, is filtering for `<tag amenity="k">`. You need to change this to `tag[@k="amenity"]` instead.

Here's an example which additionally returns the value of the `v` attribute I assume you're looking for...

```sql
declare @x xml =
N'<node id="335558025" visible="true" version="9" changeset="56753970" timestamp="2018-02-28T12:01:28Z" user="SimonPoole" uid="92387" lat="46.5116200" lon="6.6254900">
  <tag k="amenity" v="car_sharing"/>
</node>';

select
    id = OSMnode.value('@id', 'NUMERIC'),
    amenity = OSMnode.value('(tag[@k="amenity"]/@v)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
from @x.nodes('//node') as OSM(OSMnode);
```

Which yields...

```
id        amenity
335558025 car_sharing
```